# simple countdown in a toast using edit text

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a simple countdown from a text edit. I then created the edit text and the recovery value contained in it and then I made a while. follows the code.

```
while(counter<second) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Countdown: "+counter++, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    counter++;

    if(counter==second) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The variable second is an int

```
String seconds = editText.getText().toString();
second = Integer.valueOf(seconds);
```

When I execute my code malfunctioning showing the wrong numbers. where is the error(s)?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what are the "wrong numbers" that you see?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
while(counter<second) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Countdown: "+counter++, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    counter++;

                    if(counter==second) {
                        break;
                    }
```

to

```
while(counter<second) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Countdown: "+counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    counter++;

                    if(counter==second) {
                        break;
                    }
```

you were incrementing your counter twice per loop

Answer (score 1):

Better way of implementing a countdown:: change the code below to start the timer with a button click once you input your value in the edittext:

```
 int a = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText()); //total time for the timer in millis

    new CountDownTimer(a, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             Toast.makeText(context,"seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             Toast.makeText(context,"done!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      }.start();
```

Comment: I think we can not show Toasts in threads where Looper is not prepared. and if I am correct, your code will throw exception...

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is possible and will have to implications! Try it yourself